# Impute Column Outliers with Column median within a Dataframe

Tags: r

is there a known function for doing this..?
Id like to apply this to certain columns within my numerical dataframe so that outliers are replaced with Column median.

Comment: Try typing `?replace` and `?median`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example. One way would be the following:

Assuming that you are using the [interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) to identify outliers you could do this:

Example data:

```
#the first 3 rows are outliers here in both columns
set.seed(100)
mydf <- data.frame(a = c(1000,1000,1000,runif(10)), b= c(1000,1000,1000,runif(10)))
```

I am using the following function that essentially converts the outliers of each column (outlier is any point that is less than the 25% quartile minus 1.5 times the IQR **OR** more than the 75% quartile plus 1.5 times the IQR) into the median:

```
outlier <- function(x) {
 x[x < quantile(x,0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x,0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x)] <- median(x)
 x
}
```

Output (using `lapply` to apply to each column):

```
> mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, outlier)
> mydf
            a         b
1  0.48377074 0.6690217
2  0.48377074 0.6690217
3  0.48377074 0.6690217
4  0.30776611 0.6249965
5  0.25767250 0.8821655
6  0.55232243 0.2803538
7  0.05638315 0.3984879
8  0.46854928 0.7625511
9  0.48377074 0.6690217
10 0.81240262 0.2046122
11 0.37032054 0.3575249
12 0.54655860 0.3594751
13 0.17026205 0.6902905
```

As you can see the outliers (values of 1000 in the original data.frame i.e. the first three rows in both columns) have been replaced with the median.

Comment: Np, glad I could be of help :)